# Take dictionaries d1 and d2 and returns a new dictionary that contains all the keys from d1 that are not in d2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Take dictionaries d1 and d2 and returns a new dictionary that contains all
the keys from d1 that are not in d2.

Comment: What is *your question?*

Comment: that is not too hard; even for a newcomer. What have you tried?

Comment: It's a frequent question appearing every week here, where you got stuck - can you show your attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
d2 = {'a':1, 'c':3}

d3 = {key:val for key, val in d1.items() if not key in d2.keys()}
```

Comment: You don't need `.keys()`, just `... key in d2` will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set.difference` to get only the keys from the first dictionary, and use dictionary comprehension to get only the key value pairs in the first dictionary resulting from the subset of keys.

```py
>>> d1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4}
>>> d2 = {'a':1, 'c':3}

>>> {k:d1[k] for k in set(d1).difference(d2)}
#output
{'b': 2, 'd': 4}
```

Comment: Instead of `set(d1).difference(d2)`, use `d1.keys() - d2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's dictionary comprehension for a pretty self explanatory code.

```py
d1 = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 3}
d2 = {'c': 3, 'd': 4}

# for every key "k" in d1, add it to result if "k" is not on d2
# k: d1[k] just means to add "key: value" from d1
result = {k: d1[k] for k in d1 if k not in d2}
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example:

```
d1= {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
d2= {1:'a',4:'b',5:'c'}
d3= {}
for key, val in d1.items():
    if key not in d2.keys():
        d3.update({key:val})
print(d3)
```

Output:

```
{2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```